# Where to put sortBy('name') in the controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

The following controller doesn't result in any `ships`. If I delete

```
model = model.sortBy('name');
```

it results in all `ships` but obviously they are not sorted by the `name` attribute.

*How can I fix this?*

**app/controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCompany: null,

  companies: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.companies');
    return model;
  }.property('model.companies'),

  ships: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.ships');
    model = model.sortBy('name');
    return model;
  }.property('model.ships')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Ember.computed.sort` might be the easiest way to go if you only want to have those ships sorted (see answer by Kori John Roys), this doesn't address what's going wrong in your code.

In short: You're trying to sort the promise, not the data. To sort the data you'd have to do the following:

```
...
return model.then(function(data){return data.sortBy('name');})
...
```

Now the sorting is done on the actual data once the promise has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably lean towards using computed properties here, specifically [sort](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCompany: null,
  companies: Ember.computed.alias('model.companies'),
  shipSort: ['name:asc'],

  sortedShips: Ember.computed.sort('model.ships', 'shipSort')
});
```

Bonus: [working js-bin](http://jsbin.com/xaqaqe/1/edit?html,js,output)